# Change PFFile size limit in Parse Server on Azure

Tags: azure, parse-platform

I have my own Parse Server in Azure following this tutorial 
[here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-publication-of-parse-server-with-azure-managed-services/)

now I want to change size limit of PFFile

I know there is option called maxUploadSize in
[FilesRouter.js](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/d5940b17b6914f04462420812aed9efe54a2b37f/src/Routers/FilesRouter.js#L22)

but how to access it and modify it on Azure ?

this is my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the App Service Editor (available in the menu of your App Service) to edit any file within the Parse system.

Comment: Thank you , but I can't find FilesRouter.js file or maxUploadSize option when I use the search button in App Service Editor

Answer (score 0):

`FilesRouter.js` is in `src/` but that probably isn't what you want.

the `maxUploadSize` config options defaults to 20mb which you can see [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/ca286b7108197034a3ff02063a259ff12181a329/src/defaults.js#L28)

So there are two things you need to look at to increase the size:

1. What if any constraint does Azure put on your uploads and how do you set that.  I don't know the answer to this.
2. If the file is greater than 20mb, then you need to set the `maxUploadSize` when you are configuring the server.  So you don't need to edit any source code, you just need to set a config value.  So how are you starting and setting the server config values?